# How can I crawl the specific content in this html with Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a html like this：

```
<tr>
<td>
<b>
<a href=".././statistics/power" title="Exponent of the power-law degree distribution">Power law exponent (estimated) with d<sub>min</sub></a>
</b>
</td>
<td>2.1310 (d<sub>min</sub> = 49) 
</td>
</tr>
```

Besides, I have **many other html almost same as this one but have different numbers in the third line from the bottom**.
I want to crawl these numbers like 2.1310 in this html but don't know what to do.

Here is my code:

```
def getLinks(Url):
    html=urlopen(Url)
    s = '<tr><td><b><a href=".././statistics/power" title' \
    '="Exponent of the power-law degree distibution">Power law exponent (estimated) with ' \
    'd<sub>min</sub></a></b></td><td>2.1310(d<sub>min</sub> = 49) </td></tr>'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.find_all('td')[1].contents[0][:-2])
```

I can get 2.1310 using this code.

But when **the number is changed**, I don't know how to define an **unified** 's' when facing other html. There are so many similar htmls that I can not copy everyone when codeing.

Comment: you can just use regex to catch all the decimal values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex to extract the Float value.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
s = '<tr><td><b><a href=".././statistics/power" title' \
    '="Exponent of the power-law degree distibution">Power law exponent (estimated) with ' \
    'd<sub>min</sub></a></b></td><td>2.1610(d<sub>min</sub> = 2) </td></tr>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    m = re.search("\d+\.\d+", tr.text)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

**Output:**

```
2.1610
```

Comment: I just edit my question. When the number is changed, how can I define an unified 's'?

Comment: I have about 1000 similar html which only differ in the number. For example, in the second html, it is not 2,1610 but 3.2302, in the third, it is 3.5610. I want to use a function and recycle it to get those numbers in each html.

Comment: `m = re.search("\d+\.\d+", tr.text)` should work on all of that.....The Regex is searching for a decimal in the text

Comment: Oh, I understand now!